# Issue accessing local NAS via NFS when opevpn service enabled

Tags: networking, vpn, openvpn, nfs, nas

I have a VM running Ubuntu 22.04 and i have been having some issues with mounting a local NFS share to the VM when the openvpn NordVPN client connection is running. I believe the issue is that request for the NFS connection is reaching out over the VPN rather than the local LAN connection. Does anyone know how to route any requests on the 192.168.8.0/24 subnet to the LAN and not the VPN interface?

I have tried running the following on startup of the openvpn connection to make sure applications running on the local network do not route over the vpn:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip rule add from $(ip route get 1 | grep -Po '(?<=src )(\S+)') table 128
ip route add table 128 to $(ip route get 1 | grep -Po '(?<=src )(\S+)')/32 dev $(ip -4 route ls | grep default | grep -Po '(?<=dev )(\S+)')
ip route add table 128 default via $(ip -4 route ls | grep default | grep -Po '(?<=via )(\S+)')
```

and i also have the following in my openvpn .conf file that runs on startup of openvpn:

```
pull-filter ignore redirect-gateway
route 192.168.8.0 255.255.255.0 net_gateway
```

Does anyone know what i might need to add/remove in order to get this to work?

**TLDR**: I am trying to connect to a NFS share on my LAN but route all other traffic outbound through my vpn client running on the machine.

Thanks!

EDIT:
output of `ip route` command after running `ip route add 192.168.8.0/24 dev eth0` after vpn client startup.

```
0.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.1.1 dev tun0
default via 192.168.8.1 dev ens18 proto dhcp src 192.168.8.114 metric 100
10.8.1.0/24 dev tun0 proto kernel scope link src 10.8.1.14
128.0.0.0/1 via 10.8.1.1 dev tun0
181.214.226.148 via 192.168.8.1 dev ens18
192.168.8.0/24 dev ens18 scope link
192.168.8.0/24 dev ens18 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.8.114 metric 100
192.168.8.1 dev ens18 proto dhcp scope link src 192.168.8.114 metric 100
```

Comment: *I believe the issue is that request for the NFS connection is reaching out over the VPN rather than the local LAN connection.* **Bingo**  you could add the rout manually for testing by typing 'sudo ip route add 192.168.8.0/24 via dev eth0' replace eth0 by your ethernet interface. In case of an error message try again without **via** 'sudo ip route add 192.168.8.0/24 dev eth0' To make it permanent you need to modify the openvpn-client.conf but i am not familiar with openvpn. With 'ip route' you can check your routes before and after acrivating the vpn.

Comment: @AlexOnLinux I have tried running the VPN normally with none of the above configs included and only running the `ip route add 192.168.8.0/24 dev eth0` command after the VPN has started and is running and i still get the same issue. Any other ideas? see above for my `ip route` after running the command with vpn server running

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright so I figured out the issue. The script I was using above was not executing before the openvpn client connected. Thus it was adding route rules that acted on the vpn network information. If it ran before the vpn started then it would have been fine. So all I did was hard-code in the values to this to make it work:

```
#!/bin/sh
ip rule add from 192.168.8.114 table 128
ip route add table 128 to 192.168.8.0/24 dev ens18
ip route add table 128 default via 192.168.8.1
```

Now i can connect to the server locally and it is able to attach to the NFS server!

Comment: u should mark your answer as solution too == question solved^^